# With /WX compiler option, Visual C++ should not build my program, but it does

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings, compiler-options

Having set the /WX compiler option, this code should not compile, but it does:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
//#pragma warning( disable : 4005 ) // macro redefinition

#define TEST_MACRO 123

    std::cout << TEST_MACRO;

#define TEST_MACRO 456

    std::cout << TEST_MACRO;
}
```

This is Visual C++ output:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: TestWarningDisable, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>TestWarningDisable.cpp
1>E:\test\TestWarningDisable\TestWarningDisable.cpp(14,1): warning C4005: 'TEST_MACRO': macro redefinition
1>E:\test\TestWarningDisable\TestWarningDisable.cpp(10): message : see previous definition of 'TEST_MACRO'
1>TestWarningDisable.vcxproj -> E:\test\TestWarningDisable\Debug\TestWarningDisable.exe
1>Done building project "TestWarningDisable.vcxproj".
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Why isn't warning C4005 converted to an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the problem: I set the /WX option for a x64 build, but then I made a Win32 build.

This was a quick test project, and it is strange that Visual Studio created a simple empty Win32 project and when I changed the project properties the dialog was set to x64 by default...